# Cannot capture IE11, MS Word 2013 with single window on Win 8.1

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a issue related to capture a specific window. I used getWindowDC(hwnd) on window 7. Almost of them are OK.

But I captured IE11, MS Word 2013 on window 8.1, content of images are white images. I think because IE11, MS Office 2013 on Windows 8.1 is using non-GDI technology, the capture cannot get correctly, is that right?

I would like to capture a specific window on Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, but I cannot find other API can replace `getWindowDC(hwnd)`.

I used the code of  `GetWindowDC(hwnd)` as below:
`DC hDC = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
BitBlt(BitmapDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY /* |CAPTUREBLT */);
ReleaseDC(hDC, hDC);`
image captured:

[image]

Comment: You can't "capture" windows this way. You are making the assumption that the window's entire contents will be contained on the bitmap selected into the window's device context. There's no guarantee that will be the case. If you want a window to draw itself into a particular device context, send the WM_PRINT message.

Comment: Hi Cody Gray, 
I call printWindow() API then get capture window. Result capture is correct. 
But with UWP applications in window 10, the capture cannot get correctly.